# Proving a function is big O

Tags: discrete-mathematics, asymptotics

How would I go about proving a function is big O? Do I use the regular proofs (direct, contrapositive, contradiction)?

Example:
Prove that $x^n$ is $O(n!)$ for every real number $x$.

My proof by contradiction:
If $x^n$ is $O(n!)$ then there does not exist $C$ and $K$ such that $|f(x)| \leq C|g(x)|$ whenever $x>K$.
But $x^n<C(n!)$ when $C>x^n$ for all numbers, a contradiction right?

Comment: That looks good to me...

Comment: Sorry, that is not a proof, and it is not a question of minor missing bits. You basically need to show that for any fixed $x$, there is an $N$ and a $C$ such that $|x^n|\lt Cn!$ for **every** $n\gt N$. You cannot adjust the $C$ when you meet a new $n$. The same $C$ has to work for **all** big enough $n$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For every $x\in\mathbb{R}$, the series
$$
e^x=\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{x^n}{n!}
$$
converges.

In particular, the general term tends to $0$.

So
$$
\frac{x^n}{n!}=O(1)\qquad\Rightarrow \qquad x^n=O(n!).
$$

**Alternative** (since you don't know series): set $a_n:=x^n/n!$.

Then
$$
\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}}=\frac{x}{n+1}\longrightarrow 0.
$$
In particular, there exists $N$ such that
$$
\frac{|a_{n+1}|}{|a_n|}\leq\frac{1}{2}\quad\forall n\geq N.
$$
Then an easy induction shows
$$
|a_n|\leq \frac{|a_N|}{2^{n-N}}\qquad \forall n\geq N.
$$
Therefore, by the squeeze theorem, we have
$$
\lim a_n=\lim \frac{x^n}{n!}=0.
$$
In particular, the sequence $x^n/n!$ is bounded, say by $C>0$, 
$$
\frac{|x^n|}{n!}\leq C \quad\Rightarrow\quad |x^n|\leq Cn!\quad\forall n\geq 0.
$$
The last expression reads
$$
x^n=O(n!).
$$

Comment: That looks foreign to me, we havent started series yet so im assuming we would have to give an answer without them. Are you saying C would be x^n/n! and K would be 0. This would work for all any x.

Comment: @Infodayne Here is a series-free proof.